# Displaying Images from a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a JS snippet to display an overlay on a webpage and need to scrape the images, save them to a variable, and display them on a overlay.

I currently have the images I need in an array:

```
var itemImages = $(".itemImg img");
var imageArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < itemImages.length; i++) {
  imageArray.push("<li><img src='" + itemImages[i].src + "'/></li>");
}
```

The image array looks like this:

```
["<li><img src='http://cdnmedia.marmot.com/images/product/tile/75940_9149_f.jpg'/></li>", "<li><img src='http://cdnmedia.marmot.com/images/product/tile/18840_001_f.jpg'/></li>"]
```

I can seem to figure out how to display these in my code.  The function currently looks like this:

```
function displayModal(itemCount, imageArray, cartTotal) {
  $("<article id='modal'><div id='itemCount'>" + "Total Items: " 
    + itemCount + "<br><div id=itemImages>" + "<div id='images'>" + "IMAGES!" +
    "</div></div></div></article>").css({
    "width": "461px",
    "height": "263px",
    "line-height": "200px",
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "50%",
    "margin-top": "-155px",
    "margin-left": "-232px",
    "background-color": "rgb(255,255,255)",
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "text-align": "center",
    "z-index": 101,
    "border": "1px solid rgb(227,227,227)",
    "border-top": "4px solid rgb(217,0,31)"
  }).appendTo("#overlay");
  $("#itemCount").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "bottom": "79px",
    "font-family": "Helvetica",
    "color": "#000",
    "font-size": "16px"
  }).appendTo("#modal");
}
```

I'm using the place-holding IMAGES! for the actual images.  I can't seem to display the images themselves, only the word "object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is because you're referencing the `imageArray` array - which is an object - but what you want are the elements within the array.

You can retrieve the individual items in the array in a similar way to how you first added them, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
      var image = imageArray[i];
    }
```

Or you could build up a string of all your image HTML by adding the following to the beginning of your `displayModal` function:

```
    var imageHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
      imageHTML += imageArray[i];
    }
```

and adding `imageHTML` into your generated HTML in place of `"IMAGES!"`

I've added a [working example to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s94gf5ux/)

Comment: I build up my a string of my image HTML.  And it looks as follows:  "<li><img src='http://cdnmedia.marmot.com/images/product/tile/75940_9149_f.jpg'/></li><li><img src='http://cdnmedia.marmot.com/images/product/tile/18840_001_f.jpg'/></li>"  However, when I add this as an argument to my function, it is still returning two objects.

Comment: Would you be able to post your complete code, or create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see exactly what's going on?

Comment: Sure, here is the var function: 

var cartTotal = parseFloat($("#subTotal").text().match(/\d+/));
var itemCount = parseInt($("#navShoppingCart").text().match(/\d+/));
var itemImages = $(".itemImg img");
var imageHTML = "";
for (i = 0; i < itemImages.length; i++) {
  imageHTML += "<li><img src='" + itemImages[i].src + "'/></li>";
}

Comment: I think I see the problem - I've updated my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Now I am getting the following displayed on the screen [object HTMLImageElement][object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: I've added a link to a JSFiddle showing the whole thing working.  Hope this helps!